# How to mock a decorated class in an integration test

Tags: .net, integration-testing, inversion-of-control, decorator, castle-windsor

We use Castle Windsor in our project. We have `Installer : IWindsorInstaller` class which contains `Install` method with all registrations for a particular project.

Now I want to write an integration test which will test some "happy scenario" on all classes, with just mocked data source. It means I want to use a mocked data source instead of normal SQL data source used in production code.

The problem is caused by the fact that the data source is decorated using Castle Windsor's decorator support. It means that I register the chain of decorators at first (in some wanted order), then register the real data source. The integration test wants to call the `Install` method of the production code, but needs to put there a mocked data source instead of the real one. If there were no decorators, we can simply use `IsDefault` to force container to use mock instead of originally registered production class. But this isn't possible with decorators, because it overwrites the whole chain of decorators.

In production code the chain is like: Client -> Cache -> Computation -> DataSource

In integration test I want chain like: Client -> Cache -> Computation -> MockedData

The code in `Install` looks like:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository, ICacheService<int, List<MyData>>>().ImplementedBy<MyDataCache>());
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<ComputedColumns>());
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<DataRepository>());
```

What I need now is to skip the last one of registrations. But if I write a separate registration code in the integration test, it won't test if the Install method is correctly written. I am trying to find a solution which will work together with Install method from production code.

What I tried so far: Since I haven't found any real solution by Castle Windsor, I split `Install` method to two methods, and production code calls both of them to register everything, but integration test doesn't call that one which contains the last registration. Unfortunately, this solution requires that production code calls those two Install methods in particular order, or it doesn't work. So again I created some dangerous piece of code which is untestable with normal NUnit tests. (And this is read, I mistakenly reversed the order of those registrations and it wasn't visible until somebody used it in production code...)

Answer (score 1):

> In production code the chain is like: Client -> Cache -> Computation
>   -> DataSource
>
> In integration test I want chain like: Client -> Cache -> Computation -> MockedData

From such formulation of the task, it's very clear for me that `Installer` should be parameterized with the type of data source (`DataSource` or `MockedData`).

Since `Installer` implements Castle `IWindsorInstaller` interface and you can't change the method `Install`, you could make `Installer` class a generic with type of data source:

```
public class Installer<TDataRepository> : IWindsorInstaller where TDataRepository : IRepository
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository, ICacheService<int, List<MyData>>>().ImplementedBy<MyDataCache>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<ComputedColumns>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<TDataRepository>());
    }
}
```

Now you could setup required implementation, different for production code and integration test:

```
//  In production code
container.Install(new Installer<DataRepository>());

//  In integration test
container.Install(new Installer<MockedRepository>());
```

Such solution does not have any drawbacks of "two methods" approach that you described.

Comment: We cannot do exactly this because our installers are called automatically by convention. I mean my code is in a plugin and I don't have an access to container. System just scans the assembly for all IWindsorInstaller implementations and call them.

Comment: I think this answer is more a workaround then real solution to my question. I can do the registrations somehow myself, of course. What I want to achieve is to be able to use the real production-code Installer in the integration test and just tweak some particular registrations by doing something either before or after I call the real production-code Installers.

Comment: As regards registration by convention - you could make that generic installer an abstract class (e.g. `InstallerT<TDataRepository>`) and then have concrete implementation that just inherits from `InstallerT<DataRepository>`. Windsor will correctly invoke it.

Comment: As regards your second comment - I don't see other possibility to modify decorator chain that is set up in `Install()` method. You could just add more decorators before or after, but this will not help you to avoid call to `DataSource` implementation.